# T-SQL query to for selecting from joined tables, where there's a variable number of parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

(I'm using MS SQL Server with Entity Framework, although EF is just executing some raw SQL).

I need to retrieve a bunch of data from some joined tables, but only for specific combinations of "employeeId" and "companyId" (both are needed for uniqueness). My problem is, I don't know how I can pass lists of these two params into a SQL query.

Here's my code. It's not exactly what I have, but it's a good mockup of what I'm trying to do.

```
public IEnumerable<MyDbo> GetWorkLocations(IEnumerable<EmployeeAndCompanyIdPair> employees)
{
  // These are commented out because they'll only grab the data for the first employee. 
  // They're mainly included as an example.
  //
  // var companyIdParam = new SqlParameter("@companyIdParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9) { Value = employees.First().CompanyId };
  // var employeeIdParam = new SqlParameter("@employeeIdParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9) { Value = employees.First().EmployeeId };

  var results = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyDbo>(@"
    SELECT 
        e.CompanyId
        e.EmployeeId
        w.WorkAddress
    FROM EmpInfo e
    INNER JOIN WorkLocation w on e.WorkLocationId = w.WorkLocationId
    WHERE
        e.CompanyId = @companyIdParam
        e.EmployeeId = @employeeIdParam
  ").ToList();
  
  return results;
}

// model used for the param above
public class EmployeeAndCompanyIdPair
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

An an example, I might want to pass a list into the method above that looks like this:

```
{CompanyId: "P555", EmployeeId: "12345"},
{CompanyId: "P555", EmployeeId: "12346"},
{CompanyId: "P555", EmployeeId: "12347"},
{CompanyId: "P777", EmployeeId: "54321"},
{CompanyId: "P777", EmployeeId: "54322"}
```

How can I make it so that the SQL query can accept a variable number of two parameters like this?

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to enumerate your `employees` and build a dynamic query, e.g. something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyDbo> GetWorkLocations(IEnumerable<EmployeeAndCompanyIdPair> employees)
{
  var query = new StringBuilder();
  query.Append(@"
    SELECT 
        e.CompanyId
        e.EmployeeId
        w.WorkAddress
    FROM EmpInfo e
    INNER JOIN WorkLocation w on e.WorkLocationId = w.WorkLocationId
    WHERE

");

  var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
  var employeesArray = employees.ToArray();
  var count = employees.Length;
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    query.AppendLine($"(e.CompanyId = @companyIdParam{i} AND e.EmployeeId = @employeeIdParam{i})");

    if (i != count-1) {
        query.AppendLine(" OR ");
    }

    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@companyIdParam{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9) { Value = employeesArray[i].CompanyId });

    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@employeeIdParam{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9) { Value = employeesArray[i].EmployeeId });
  }

  var results = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyDbo>(query.ToString(), parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
  
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, so instead of just trying a one-size-fits-all query, I can just dynamically create it with all the params included. That's brilliant! I'll give that a try, thank you.

Comment: Really should do something to handle the case where `employees` is empty.

Comment: Better yet, rather than building horrendously large queries at run time and blowing out your execution plan cache - insert your values into a temp table (or "working" table) and join to that table.